# React - conditionally not send data key in form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to omit a value `onSubmit` if a checkbox is selected, eliminating the need for a specific label/input. If I check the `indefinite runTime` box, `runTimeSeconds` key no longer needs to be sent in the payload, is this something that's done in handleSubmit method itself?

When the form is submitted, with the checkbox selected, it's still sending the `runTimeSeconds` key is still being sent with the default state value.

Here's a sandbox with replicating the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/5vvpj40rqk

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class Params extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      windowLengthSeconds: 1,
      runTimeSeconds: 1,
      indefiniteCheckbox: false
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    this.props.handleChange(e);
    console.log([e.target.value]);
    const value =
      e.target.type === "checkbox" ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;

    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { indefiniteCheckbox } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="params-boxes">
        <div className="checkbox">
          <label>Indefinite runTime:</label>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="indefiniteCheckbox"
            value={this.state.indefiniteCheckbox}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        {!indefiniteCheckbox && (
          <div>
            <label>runTimeSeconds:</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              name="runTimeSeconds"
              value={this.state.runTimeSeconds}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              placeholder="1"
              min="1"
              required
            />
          </div>
        )}
        <div>
          <label>windowLengthSeconds:</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            name="windowLengthSeconds"
            value={this.state.windowLengthSeconds}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder="1"
            min="1"
            step="1"
            required
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      runtimeSeconds: 1,
      windowLengthSeconds: 1,
      indefiniteCheckbox: false
    };
  }

  handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
    console.log([name, value]);
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    data: JSON.stringify({
      parameters: {
        "stream.runtime.seconds": this.state.runTimeSeconds,
        "stream.window.length.seconds": this.state.windowLengthSeconds
      }
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Parameters</legend>
              <div>
                <Params handleChange={this.handleChange} />
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="btn-group">
          <span className="input-group-btn">
            <button
              className="btnSubmit"
              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
              type="submit"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
            <button
              className="btnReset"
              handleCancel={this.handleCancel}
              type="reset"
              onClick={() => {
                alert(
                  "Are you sure you want to cancel? Doing so will reset this page."
                );
              }}
            >
              Cancel
            </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Note that you can likely recreate the sandbox here on Stack Overflow with [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552) so people don't have to go to another site to see the code working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices.

You can either set your data variable to `undefined` if your checkbox is checked by using a ternary condition. In the other case, the time given in the input is sent :

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        parameters: {
            "stream.runtime.seconds": !this.state.indefiniteCheckbox ? this.state.runTimeSeconds : undefined,
            "stream.window.length.seconds": this.state.windowLengthSeconds
        }
    });
};
```

Or you can create your payload in a separate variable and delete the desired value out of it if the condition matches :

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const parameters = {
        "stream.runtime.seconds": this.state.runTimeSeconds,
        "stream.window.length.seconds": this.state.windowLengthSeconds
    }
    if (!this.state.indefiniteCheckbox) delete parameters['stream.runtime.seconds']

    const data = JSON.stringify({ parameters });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Do you believe one choice should take priority over the other?

Comment: I would rather use the first one as it is more readable and does not initialize a value just to delete it afterwards. But the choice is up to you

Comment: I used the first method, and it still looks like `runTimeSeconds` is in the form state when submitted.

Comment: What do you mean with 'looks like'

Comment: With the checkbox checked, on submit the `runTimeSeconds` key and the value is still being sent in the data payload.

Comment: Are you seeing something different in the sandbox?

Comment: Weird, is the second solution giving you the same output, as `delete` will also free the memory used by the value

Comment: The first one is working, for some reason I was missing something, thank you again.

Comment: I have actually found an issue with this implementation, after check/uncheck `this.state.indefiniteCheckbox` was returning a string value "true" or "false" for the state value. It should be boolean. I have updated my sandbox so it's returning boolean values, <https://codesandbox.io/s/5vvpj40rqk>. Now all the keys are being submitted despite the value of `checked`